# Op-amp burns out

Tags: operational-amplifier, pullup, pulldown

On my PCB the input of the op-amp is shorted to VCC (28 V) or GND when the op-amp burns out (it happens a lot).

In addition I want to add protection components on the input of the op-amp; if the op-amp shorts to VCC/GND the short circuit shouldn't affect the unit before the op-amp.

Because it's on a PCB I can only add components in series or parallel to the input of the op-amp.

Some of the op-amps have a pull-up resistor and input of GND/open; other op-amps have a pull-down resistor and input of VCC/open.

[image]

Comment: What is the unit before these op-amps? LM224 max supply is 30 V ...

Comment: It looks like you took a photograph of your screen, imported it into your PC and wrote over it in paint. Tell me I'm misguided here.

Comment: @ram Please put the schematics of the previous section for better understanding of the issue. The "open" of "28/open" might be telling something.

Comment: i toke a photo of the orcad and edit in PAINT for my reasons.. that less relevant. i wrote in paint what can be in the input of the amp and added a1/a2 in the outputs so you can understade how the virual wire connected

Answer (score 3):

Well, I’m not sure anyone can be sure what is causing your problems, but you are very close to the absolute maximum supply and input voltages for that part, and your labeling hints at some possible filtering which could be complicating things. If the issue is indeed connected to input wiring and not supply transients, then a resistor of a few thousand ohms, up to maybe 10k, in series with each input at the chip itself may well cure the problem. That will cause a few mV of additional offset but no other ill effects. That  will likely involve some *minor* surgery on the board to break the trace to the input and bridge it with a SMT resistor. An additional 1N4148/LL4148 directly from each input pin to Vcc would add a bit more insurance, there is no need of a diode to GND, the LM224 provides that function internally (probably via isolation diffusion parasitic diodes).

If you are dead set against that hacking you could try adding clamps to the inputs but without a lot more information I don’t think that would be wise. I could well imagine it causing additional issues…

Comment: why dont resistor of 100k in series(in the inputs that have 28 or open)? thats will "take" 10% from the input voltage so the input smaller than the maximum input voltage